# Typescript infer union type

Tags: typescript

I have a construct like this:

```js
interface Foo<T> {
    value: T;
}

interface Bar<T> {
    value: T;
}

function transform<T>(foos: Foo<T>[]): Bar<T> {
    // ...
}
```

I want to call `transform()` like this: `transform([{ value: 'a' }, { value: 1 }])` and have that result in the type `Bar<string | number>`. However, what actually happens in the code above is that the inferred type is `string` and calling `transform()` with the second array element results in an error because `value` is a `number` and not a `string`. Is it possible to change this code to make it correctly infer the type `string | number`?

Comment: I would say you will have to use multiple signature overloads to do that just like eg RxJs has

Comment: TS doesn't like to synthesize unions from multiple inference candidates.  Instead you can make the generic type an array instead of the element, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m075GN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer (or find an appropriate dupe source).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This works perfectly, thanks. I had not thought of using `keyof T` like that.